# Iterating over dataframe then increment counter if criteria is met

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, counter

## Simplified Example

I have a CSV file that I want to go over the rows and count how many times a value appears within a certain range.  My CSV is around 500 rows, but here is a simplified example of what it looks like:

```
   Time        key
0    -5  LeftShift
1    10  LeftShift
2    20  C
3    30  LeftShift
4    40  C
```

I'm trying to count how many times the string "C" occurs within a certain time range.  I would also like to count how many times "C" occurs outside the time range.

```
import pandas as pd

# Name of file to read
filename = "test.csv"

#data frame to create from file
df = pd.read_csv(filename)

# Set counters
correct_hit = 0
incorrect_hit = 0

# Time range (milliseconds) to compare
range1 = 0
range2 = 20
range3 = 20.01
range4 = 40

if (range1 < Time <= range2) and (Key == "C"):
    incorrect_hit += 1
elif (range3 < Time <= range4) and (Key == "C"):
    correct_hit += 1
```

I have generic logic at the end of my code sample.  I'm comparing the range of time to a "Time" variable that is not defined yet.  This is where I'm stuck.

For the example I've given above I expect my output to be the counter values:

```
incorrect_hit = 1
correct_hit = 1
```

Thank you @PaSTE for your response and direction.

## Another attempt

```
import pandas as pd

# Name of file to read
filename = "TEST.csv"

#data frame to create from file
df = pd.read_csv(filename)

# Set counters 
correct_hit = 0
incorrect_hit = 0

# Time ranges (milliseconds) for correct_hits
# range1-2 & 3-4 are correct hits
range1 = 92001
range2 = 96000
range3 = 376004
range4 = 380004
# Time ranges (milliseconds) for incorrect_hits
range5 = 12000
range6 = 16000
range7 = 28000
range8 = 32000
range9 = 44001
range10 = 48001
range11 = 60000
range12 = 64001
#range 13 - 14 was incorrect hit
range13 = 76000
range14 = 80001
#
range15 = 108001
range16 = 112001
range17 = 124001
range18 = 128001
range19 = 140001
range20 = 144001
range21 = 156002
range22 = 160001
range23 = 172002
range24 = 176002
range25 = 188002
range26 = 192002
range27 = 204002
range28 = 208002
range29 = 280003
range30 = 284003
range31 = 296003
range32 = 300003
range33 = 312003
range34 = 316003
range35 = 328004
range36 = 332003
range37 = 344004
range38 = 348004
range39 = 360004
range40 = 364004
# range 41 to 42 was incorrect hit
range41 = 392004
range42 = 396005
#
range43 = 408004
range44 = 412005
range45 = 424004
range46 = 428004
range47 = 440005
range48 = 444004
range49 = 456005
range50 = 460005
range51 = 472005
range52 = 476005

# This compares the number of correct responses
condition1 = (df["Time"] >= range1) & (df["Time"] <= range2) & (df["key"] == "C")
condition2 = (df["Time"] >= range3) & (df["Time"] <= range4) & (df["key"] == "C")

correct_hit = condition1.sum() + condition2.sum()

# This compares the number of incorrect responses
condition3 = (df["Time"] >= range5) & (df["Time"] <= range6) & (df["key"] == "C")
condition4 = (df["Time"] >= range7) & (df["Time"] <= range8) & (df["key"] == "C")
condition5 = (df["Time"] >= range9) & (df["Time"] <= range10) & (df["key"] == "C")
condition6 = (df["Time"] >= range11) & (df["Time"] <= range12) & (df["key"] == "C")
condition7 = (df["Time"] >= range13) & (df["Time"] <= range14) & (df["key"] == "C")
condition8 = (df["Time"] >= range15) & (df["Time"] <= range16) & (df["key"] == "C")
condition9 = (df["Time"] >= range17) & (df["Time"] <= range18) & (df["key"] == "C")
condition10 = (df["Time"] >= range19) & (df["Time"] <= range20) & (df["key"] == "C")
condition11 = (df["Time"] >= range21) & (df["Time"] <= range22) & (df["key"] == "C")
condition12 = (df["Time"] >= range23) & (df["Time"] <= range24) & (df["key"] == "C")
condition13 = (df["Time"] >= range25) & (df["Time"] <= range26) & (df["key"] == "C")
condition14 = (df["Time"] >= range27) & (df["Time"] <= range28) & (df["key"] == "C")
condition15 = (df["Time"] >= range29) & (df["Time"] <= range30) & (df["key"] == "C")
condition16 = (df["Time"] >= range31) & (df["Time"] <= range32) & (df["key"] == "C")
condition17 = (df["Time"] >= range33) & (df["Time"] <= range34) & (df["key"] == "C")
condition18 = (df["Time"] >= range35) & (df["Time"] <= range36) & (df["key"] == "C")
condition19 = (df["Time"] >= range37) & (df["Time"] <= range38) & (df["key"] == "C")
condition20 = (df["Time"] >= range39) & (df["Time"] <= range40) & (df["key"] == "C")
condition21 = (df["Time"] >= range41) & (df["Time"] <= range42) & (df["key"] == "C")
condition22 = (df["Time"] >= range43) & (df["Time"] <= range44) & (df["key"] == "C")
condition23 = (df["Time"] >= range45) & (df["Time"] <= range46) & (df["key"] == "C")
condition24 = (df["Time"] >= range47) & (df["Time"] <= range48) & (df["key"] == "C")
condition25 = (df["Time"] >= range49) & (df["Time"] <= range50) & (df["key"] == "C")
condition26 = (df["Time"] >= range51) & (df["Time"] <= range52) & (df["key"] == "C")

incorrect_hit = condition3.sum() + condition4.sum() + condition5.sum() + condition6.sum() + condition7.sum() + condition8.sum() + condition9.sum() + condition10.sum() + condition11.sum() + condition12.sum() + condition13.sum() + condition14.sum() + condition15.sum() + condition16.sum() + condition17.sum() + condition18.sum() + condition19.sum() + condition20.sum() + condition21.sum() + condition22.sum() + condition23.sum() + condition24.sum() + condition25.sum() + condition26.sum()

print(f'The number of correct hits: {correct_hit}')
print(f'The number of incorrect hits: {incorrect_hit}')
```

## Expected Output

The number of correct hits: 2
The number of incorrect hits: 2

Which is correct.  I was trying to also get another set to find number of times "C" occured outside of the time ranges, but I wasn't successful at it, so I just deleted it from the code snippet.

Thanks again @PaSTE.  I suspect there are better ways to do this, but I think it's working for now :)

Comment: Can you add the expected output?

Comment: Your logic doesn't exactly match the problem description. For instance Time = -5 seems to fall outside of 0-20 yet neither of your if clauses would catch it.

Comment: Ya I was just ignoring the first row, as it spits out a negative value for some reason.

As far as expected output, the counters are my expected output for now.  Using the logic and values I've shown it would be:  

correct_hit = 1
incorrect_hit = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas is designed around column-wise operations, so thinking in terms of columns, you can simply make the comparisons on the columns of the DataFrame themselves, then sum up the number of `True` values.  Take the first condition:

```
condition1 = (df["Time"] > range1) & (df["Time"] <= range2) & (df["Key"] == "C")
incorrect_hit = condition1.sum()
```

This creates three Boolean Series, each with a `True` value in rows where the particular portion of the condition is met, and a `False` value where it is not met.  If you were to stack these subconditions side-by-side, you would see, for your example 5 rows:

```
   Time > 0  Time <= 20  key == C
0     False        True     False
1      True        True     False
2      True        True      True
3      True       False     False
4      True       False      True
```

The [`&` operator](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) performs an element-wise logical AND operation between these three Series, creating a final Series that looks like this:

```
0  False
1  False
2   True
3  False
4  False
```

[`Series.sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html) adds up all the values in the series, with `True` values adding 1 to the sum and `False` values adding 0.

The second condition is similar:

```
condition2 = (df["Time"] > range3) & (df["Time"] <= range4) & (df["Key"] == "C")
correct_hit = condition2.sum()
```

Comment: Thanks!  This was very helpful in understanding how to work with dataframes.  :)

Comment: When I add more ranges to compare, as my example was simplified, it doesn't seem to work.  Am I not able to compare more than two time ranges using this technique?

`# This compares the number of correct responses:


condition2 = (df["Time"] >= range1) & (df["Time"] <= range2) & (df["Time"] >= range3) & (df["Time"] <= range4) & (df["key"] == "C")
correct_hit = condition2.sum()`

Comment: If `range1`, `range2`, etc. refer to the same ranges as in your sample code, then that expression for `condition2` logically excludes all possible times.  No number `x` can satisfy both `x <= 20` and `x >= 20.1` simultaneously.  What are you trying to do with that line?